# How to Enter Multi-Input Lines in Ubuntu Terminal Using sys.stdin.readline()

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I'm having the darndest time trying to enter two lines of input for a Python program. The objective of this program is to calculate the height of a tree. We are given a program *that works* at the outset, and our job is to make it more efficient. However, before even attempting to make the code more efficient, I wanted to at least put in some inputs to ensure I am at least inputting the inputs directly.

So, for example, an input of 5 on one line and an input of 4 -1 4 1 1 would tell us that there are 5 nodes, -1 (the 1st node) is the root, 1 and 1 (the 3rd and 4th nodes) are children of the -1 (the 1st) node, and 4 and 4 (the 0th and 2nd nodes) are children of let's say the 4th. Then the program should output 3 (the height of this tree). The problem I get stuck with in this program (besides yet that I have yet to make it more optimal) is having python interpret what I mean by the inputs. So far, I have tried variations on

```
python3 tree-height.py <<< 5\ 4 -1 4 1 1
```

for example, yet the self.n snippet is spitting out an error (on the original code, so I can ensure this input works first before I try coding anything) as it's not able to sparse the second bit. Any thoughts?

Alternatively, I've also tried creating a text file (let's call this test_case), looking like

```
5\ 4 -1 4 1 1
```

and, as other attempts, also like

```
5 4 -1 4 1 1
```

and

```
5
4 -1 4 1 1
```

then trying

```
python3 tree-height.py < test_case
```

but this has also resulted in the same error.

Relevant code bits, not all of the code/mainly care about the reading in portion:

```
import sys, threading
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**7) # max depth of recursion
threading.stack_size(2**27)  # new thread will get stack of such size

#Printing to see what is being messed up
print(sys.stdin.readline())

class TreeHeight:
        def read(self):
                self.n = int(sys.stdin.readline())
                self.parent = list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split()))
                #Printing to see what is being messed up
                print("Self.n is ",self.n)
                print("self.parent is ",self.parent)

        def compute_height(self):
                # Replace this code with a faster implementation
                # Removed this bit to protect the author? It works, but I don't want to 
                  get in trouble


def main():
  tree = TreeHeight()
  tree.read()
  print(tree.compute_height())

threading.Thread(target=main).start()
```

Also: please don't reply with saying that sys.stdin.readline() is outdated/to use input(); I also much prefer that method, but I would like to (1) learn the former and (2) I am taking this while following an online course, and I would like to adhere to the auto-tester thingy that it will be using.

Edit: I've also tried this with \ and \n (and variations) (in fact, I cannot really remember all that I've tried), but I keep getting this error message:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4 -1 4 1 1'
```

Comment: Please share the actual error message you're getting - you spend a lot of time explaining what you want and what you tried (that's OK), but you don't tell us what you're getting and what you were expecting instead (or what you don't understand about it). Something that stands out about what you shared is that we can see a backslash in there, but would expect `\n`

Comment: Yes! I just did this now! :) I have tried \n as well (not while creating text documents), but, actually, the \n SHOWS up as a string character (which is problematic) with this same error as well. (Thank you! (For even taking a look at this :) I appreciate it!))

Comment: Based on that error message, it appears that the line is not being split. What happens if you remove the readline that is outside the read method?

Comment: Ah!! This worked!! (I don't understand why though??) Thank you!!

Comment: If you read a line from a file, you cannot read the same line again, unless you first call `.seek(position)` on the file (assuming you know the correct position), or reopen it.

Comment: Thank you so much! (This will definitely be a lesson I won't forget :) (as well as the here-docs and here-strings below)) **Thank you!!!**

Answer (score 0):

An backslash followed by space is not a newline.

The easiest way is with a here-doc:

```
python3 tree-height.py <<EOF
5
4 -1 4 1 1
EOF
```

If you want to use a here-string, you need to put a newline in it. You can use `$'...'` to allow you to enter a string with escape sequences.

```
python3 tree-height.py <<< $'5\n4 -1 4 1 1'
```

Comment: So, I am aware that \ on its own is not a new line[\n is], but every time I use \n I end up getting:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4 -1 4 1 1\n'
```

which I am not sure what to do with? (In fact, I got this same error with both the here-doc and the here-string) I *was* thinking changing the split character in the python code, *but* I am fearful that this will break down when putting it into more test cases for the auto-tester

Comment: Is there a reason you use `sys.stdin.readline()` instead of `input()`?

Comment: You didn't use `$'...'`, so the `\n` was treated as literal text, not a newline.

Comment: My apologies, I am new to here-strings and here-docs and I tried to watch some videos on it just now. I guess, I'm under the impression that when you do ```python3 tree-height.py <<< $'5\n4 -1 4 1 1'```, the $ character is treating \n in the whole entire string as a legitimate new line? (Perhaps, I'm not totally clear on what you are suggesting then? :3)
(Also, re: why are you not using input()? In short, sys.stdin.readline() was the way the above code was provided to me, and I am trying to adhere to it (as opposed to changing it to input(), which I much prefer))

Comment: Yes, inside `$'...'`, C-style escape sequences are processed, so `\n` becomes a newline.